# Error in sorting based on a specific column in bash

Tags: bash

Hi I am trying this thing but it doesn't work.
[image]

I know that it doesn't work because each line has different number of columns when words are separated by space but can we do the intended job any way.

Comment: Are the columns delimited with tabs or spaces?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Did you try `sort -nt $'\t' -k3,3`?

Comment: please confirm if your 'columns' are separated by tabs or spaces; if you run `head -1 animals.txt | od -c` ... does output contain any `\t` strings (this indicates a tab)

Comment: @dan Yes it's working. Columns are separarted by tabs.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** assuming the input file's columns are separated by spaces and not tabs, otherwise dan's comment - `sort -nt $'\t' -k3,3` - should suffice

---

`sort` allows us to designate the field terminator as well as which fields (and optionally substrings of fields) to sort by.

If we set the field delimiter as a linefeed (`\n`) the entire line becomes a single field.

From here we can designate a substring of field #1 to sort by; `-k1.x,1.y` says to sort by field #1 from position `x` to position `y` (with the first character of the field/line having a position of `1`).

Sample input:

```
$ cat animals.txt
         1         2         3         4         5         6
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
alpaca   Intermediate Perl         2012   Schwatz, Randal
donkey   Cisco IOS in a Nutshell   2005   Boney, James
horse    Linux in a Nutshell       2009   Siever, Ellen
```

Where:

- the first 2 lines (the scale) do not exist in the file; the scale shows us ...
- the `year` part of the line runs from position `36` to `39`

Pulling all of this into a `sort` call:

```
# sort numerically by year (ascending)

$ sort -t$'\n' -k1.36,1.39 -n animals.txt
donkey   Cisco IOS in a Nutshell   2005   Boney, James
horse    Linux in a Nutshell       2009   Siever, Ellen
alpaca   Intermediate Perl         2012   Schwatz, Randal

# sort numerically by year (descending)

$ sort -t$'\n' -k1.36,1.39 -rn animals.txt
alpaca   Intermediate Perl         2012   Schwatz, Randal
horse    Linux in a Nutshell       2009   Siever, Ellen
donkey   Cisco IOS in a Nutshell   2005   Boney, James
```

**NOTE:** assumes all lines have the `year` in the same position (ie, the contents of the file are formatted per a fixed-width scheme)

Obviously this approach requires we know the position of the `year` substring in advance; there are a few ways to determine this position ... one idea, assuming the `year` column will always be the 1st occurrence of a 4-digit substring ... use `bash` regex matching and the `BASH_REMATCH[]` array to determine the length of the line up to the 4-digit `year`, eg:

```
$ regex="^([^0-9]*)([0-9]{4}).*"
$ [[ $(head -1 animals.txt) =~ $regex ]] && typeset -p BASH_REMATCH
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="alpaca   Intermediate Perl         2012   Schwatz, Randal" [1]="alpaca   Intermediate Perl         " [2]="2012")
```

From this we see that the `BASH_REMATCH[1]` contains the contents of the line up to the `year` (`2012` for the `alpaca` line); now we grab the length of `BASH_REMATCH[1]` and add +1/+3 to get our `x` and `y` values:

```
$ (( x = ${#BASH_REMATCH[1]} + 1 ))
$ (( y = x + 3 ))
$ typeset -p x y
declare -- x="36"
declare -- y="39"
```

Plugging these variables into our previous `sort` call:

```
# sort numerically by year (ascending)

$ sort -t$'\n' -k1.${x},1.${y} -n animals.txt
donkey   Cisco IOS in a Nutshell   2005   Boney, James
horse    Linux in a Nutshell       2009   Siever, Ellen
alpaca   Intermediate Perl         2012   Schwatz, Randal

# sort numerically by year (descending)

$ sort -t$'\n' -k1.${x},1.${y} -rn animals.txt
alpaca   Intermediate Perl         2012   Schwatz, Randal
horse    Linux in a Nutshell       2009   Siever, Ellen
donkey   Cisco IOS in a Nutshell   2005   Boney, James
```

**NOTE:** OP hasn't defined a secondary sort requirement in the case of multiple lines having the same date but it shouldn't be too hard to extend this answer to include a secondary (and tertiary?) sort requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a seperator like a comma, as from there you will be able to use the `sort` command with the `-t` argument and specify the given field separator.

To find and replace a character with a seperator I would use `cat animals.txt | sed {insert the pattern}`.

Based on the file you've shared, you could attempt addding the seperator after the first word, and before and after the numerical values.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** assuming the input file's columns are separated by spaces and not tabs, otherwise dan's comment - `sort -nt $'\t' -k3,3` - should suffice

---

If `GNU awk` is available we can have `awk` find the index for the `year` substring and then sort the output for us.

Sample input:

```
$ cat animals.txt
         1         2         3         4         5         6
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
alpaca   Intermediate Perl         2012   Schwatz, Randal
donkey   Cisco IOS in a Nutshell   2005   Boney, James
horse    Linux in a Nutshell       2009   Siever, Ellen
```

Where:

- the first 2 lines (the scale) do not exist in the file; the scale shows us ...
- the `year` part of the line runs from position `36` to `39`

One `GNU awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==1 { x=match($0, /[0-9]{4}/) }                # find index of the "year" substring in the 1st line of input; assumes the "year" is the 1st occurrence of a 4-digit substring
       { arr[substr($0,x,4)][FNR]=$0 }            # populate 2-dimensional array using "year" and row number (FNR) as indexes
END    { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"     # sort indexes as numbers in "asc"ending order
         for (i in arr)
             for (j in arr[i])
                 print arr[i][j]
       }
' animals.txt
```

This generates:

```
donkey   Cisco IOS in a Nutshell   2005   Boney, James
horse    Linux in a Nutshell       2009   Siever, Ellen
alpaca   Intermediate Perl         2012   Schwatz, Randal
```

If we change the sort order from `@ind_num_asc` to `@ind_num_desc` we can generate the output in descending `year` order, ie:

```
alpaca   Intermediate Perl         2012   Schwatz, Randal
horse    Linux in a Nutshell       2009   Siever, Ellen
donkey   Cisco IOS in a Nutshell   2005   Boney, James
```

**NOTES:**

- `GNU awk` required for multi-dimensional array (aka array of arrays) support
- `GNU awk` required for the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` feature
- assumes the entire file can fit into memory (due to storing all lines in the array)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to copy the year to the start of each line with `sed`, `sort` the resulting output numerically, and then remove the year at the start of each line:

```
sed 's/^.*[[:space:]]\([12][09][0-9][0-9]\)[[:space:]].*$/\1 &/' animals.txt \
    | sort -n | sed 's/^.....//'
```

The output with the example `animals.txt` in the question is:

```
oryx    Writing Word Macros     1999    Roman, Steven
donkey  Cisco IOS in a Nutshell 2005    Boney, James
snail   SSH, The Secure Shell   2005    Barrett, Daniel
horse   Linux in a Nutshell     2009    Sievers, Ellen
python  Programming Python      2010    Lutz, Mark
alpaca  Intermediate Perl       2012    Schwartz, Randal
robin   MySQL High Availability 2014    Bell, Charles
```